# python pandas: mean scores per hour per workday

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a database that has votes in it. These vote records consist of:
"Timestamp ; score"

The score is an integer.

I want to create a heatmap, so i want to have a dataframe with values for each hour in every workday with a mean score of all scores in that timeframe.

If there are no values in the hour of that workday, set the mean to 0.

Thusfar i've come to this:

```
gdf = pd.read_sql("select * from scores where survey_id='{}';    ".format(survey_id), self.db_conn)
gdf = gdf.set_index(['time_stamp'])
gdf.index = pd.to_datetime(gdf.index, unit='s')
if len(gdf) == 0:
  return None
gdf['weekday'] = gdf.index.weekday
# gdf['hour'] = gdf.index.hour
gdf = gdf.groupby(by=[gdf['weekday'], pd.Grouper(freq='H')]).agg(['mean']).fillna(0)
```

The result of this is:

```
                                score weekday hour
                             mean    mean mean
weekday time_stamp                                
0       2018-10-22 17:00:00  1.600000       0   17
1       2018-10-23 09:00:00  2.666667       1    9
2       2018-10-31 14:00:00  3.000000       2   14
        2018-10-31 19:00:00  4.000000       2   19
```

This misses all the other hours of the week with the 0 value as mean.

Any suggestions to what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks !! :)

Comment: I think I'd do mostly what you've done (breaking the time_stamp out to days/hours, then grouping and getting the mean). Then I'd generate a dataframe with every combination of days/hours and left join my mean data onto it, so that all the missed rows are NA and I can fill them with `.fillna(0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it:

This worked, don't know if it could have been shorter but this did the job:

- make new dataframe with 0 values for each hour of each workday.
- appended the values from the database

<

```
    todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    index = pd.date_range(todays_date - datetime.timedelta(7), periods=7*24, freq='H')
    columns = ['user', 'survey_id', 'score']
    df_ = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
    df_ = df_.fillna(0)  # with 0s rather than NaNs
    gdf = pd.read_sql("select * from scores where survey_id='{}'; ".format(survey_id), self.db_conn)
    gdf = gdf.set_index(['time_stamp'])
    gdf.index = pd.to_datetime(gdf.index, unit='s')
    df_ = df_.append(gdf, ignore_index=False)  # ignoring index is optional

    if len(gdf) == 0:
        return None
    df_['weekday'] = df_.index.weekday
    df_['hour'] = df_.index.hour
    df_ = df_.groupby(by=[df_['weekday'], df_['hour']]).agg(['mean']).fillna(0)
```